# Dynamically Add and Remove Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I am both adding and removing table rows with jQuery. I can add rows easily, but am having trouble removing ones that were created.

You can view the page in action here: http://freshbaby.com/v20/wic/request_quote.cfm, with the relevant code pasted below.

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:600px;" id="product-list" summary="Lists details about products users wish to purchase">
    <thead valign="top" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th>Products</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody valign="top" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <cfselect query="getProductListing" name="product" size="1" display="name" value="name" queryPosition="below">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </cfselect>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="language" size="1">
                    <option value="English">English</option>
                    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <cfinput name="quantity" required="yes" message="Enter your desired quantity" size="10" maxlength="3" mask="999">
            </td>
            <td valign="bottom"><a href="javascript://" class="addrow">Add Another Product</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var i = 1;
            $(".addrow").click(function() {
                $("table#product-list tbody > tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr({
                      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
                      'value': ''               
                    });
                }).end().find("a.addrow").removeClass('addrow').addClass('removerow').text('< Remove This Product')
                .end().appendTo("table#product-list tbody");
                i++;
                return false;
            });

            $("a.removerow").click(function() {
                    //This should traverse up to the parent TR
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click the link to remove the row that said link is contained in, nothing happens. No script error, so it has to be logic.

Comment: Try using `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` instead. If that doesn't work, try using `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;`, but put it at the top of your function.

Comment: It does not; see why in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$("#product-list").on('click','a.removerow',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //This should traverse up to the parent TR
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

This will ensure that newly created elements can be removed. When you use the `$("a.removerow").click(..`  it only affects the elements in existence (none) and not the ones that will be dynamically created.

Comment: Good answer, AND I learned something new about non-existent element interaction. Wonderful!